# Cordova - Modify Build/Platform Folder Location

Tags: cordova, cordova-cli

Is there a way to modify the build/platform path within Cordova so that when I run:

```
cordova platform add android
```

and

```
cordova build android
```

...it uses a custom folder path location other than the platforms folder within the base folder of the project?

Comment: why do you need to do that ?

Comment: if you want your build file to be uploaded or copied on some other location,which is a usual practice! You can write any grunt or gulp task for that. This is not a usual practice to change build path.

Comment: @mudasserajaz Makes sense. I get that it would be usual practice to not change the build path, but for the sake of the question... let's just say that I don't like the name "platforms" and would like it to be named "my_devices". Is there a setting to change the path?

Comment: @aWebDeveloper None yet

Comment: ........ And none yet :D